# Redshift SQL - Skipped sequence

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working on applicant pipeline data and need to get a count of applicants who made it to each phase of the pipeline/funnel.  If an applicant skips a phase, I need to need to count them in the phase anyway.  Here's an example of how that data might look for one applicant:

```
Stage name | Entered on
Application Review | 9/7/2018
Recruiter Screen | 9/10/2018
Phone Interview | blank
Interview | 9/17/2018
Interview 2 | 9/20/2018
Offer | blank
```

this is what the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE application_stages (
application_id bigint,
stage_id bigint,
entered_on timestamp without time zone,
exited_on timestamp without time zone,
stage_name character varying
);
```

In this example, I want to count Application Review through Interview 2 (including the skipped/blank Phone Interview phase), but not the Offer. How would I write the above in SQL? (Data is stored in Amazon Redshift.  Using SQL workbench to query.)

Also, please let me know if there is anything else I can add to my question to make the issue/solution clearer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should be providing text data rather than screen shot. Also it would be good if you add scheme of table.

Comment: Appreciate the guidance!  I'll update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the SQL I ended up with.  Thanks for the ideas, @AlexYes!

```
select stage_name,  
application_stages.application_id, entered_on, 
case when entered_on is NULL then lead(entered_on,1) 
ignore nulls
over 
(PARTITION BY application_stages.application_id order by case stage_name 
when 'Application Review' then 1 
when 'Recruiter Screen' then 2 
when 'Phone Interview' then 3
when 'Interview' then 4
when 'Interview 2' then 5
when 'Offer' then 6
when 'Hired' then 7 end) else entered_on end as for_count, exited_on
from application_stages
```

I realize that the above SQL doesn't give me the counts but I am doing the counts in Tableau.  Happy to have the format above in case I need to do other calculations on the new "for_count" field.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode the stages of the pipeline in `event_list` table like this:

```
id | stage_name
1 | first stage 
2 | second stage 
3 | third stage 
4 | fourth stage
```

UPD: The deeper is the stage of the funnel, the higher is its ID. This way, you can compare them, i.e. `third stage` is deeper than `second stage` because `3>2`. Thus, if you need to find people that reached the 2nd stage it includes people that have events with id=2 OR events with id>2, i.e. events deeper in the funnel.

If the `second stage` is missed and the `third stage` is recorded for some person you can still count that person as "reached second stage" by joining your event data to this table by `stage_name` and counting the number of records with `id>=2`, like

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from event_data t1
join event_list t2
using (stage_name)
where t2.id>=2
```

Alternatively, you can left join your event table to `event_list` and fill the gaps using `lag` function that returns the value of the previous row (i.e. assigning the timestamp of `first stage` to the `second stage` in the case above)

Comment: Say you were using this for counting phone interview, wouldn't this count twice, once each for interview1 and 2 for the above example? This is a good start, but you then need to count the distinct application_ids.

Comment: @AlexYes sometimes the blanks are correct and should not be counted.  Like in this example, Offer is blank and should not be counted because it is the final phase.  Does your suggestion still work?  Also, the blank can be in any phase, not always id 2.  It's possible that there would be multiple blanks.

Comment: @WilsonS I've added more detailed explanation to the post, hope it will make sense. If you want to count the Offer you will still be able to do it correctly because this is the deepest events and only true non-blanks will be counted.

Comment: @DancingFool sure! I've edited the query. This is obvious, I was more concentrated on the method of filling the gaps.

Comment: Thanks for the updated SQL.  Will the id>=2 work if the first stage is skipped?  Also, I don't have update access to the redshift DB.  Would I still be able to create an event_list table as you have suggested?  How would that work? Maybe a case statement to assign an id to each phase?     I am going to try the lag suggestion.  I provided a copy of the table via pastebin earlier.  Feel free to look there.  I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: @WilsonS if you want to count the N of people at stage 1 you will use `id>=1` which means stage 1 or deeper.

Comment: @WilsonS if you have only read permissions, you can use a case statement sure! as for your copy of table I'm not using it, this is too much. SO is just a QA platform and we're not supposed to provide full assistance

Comment: @AlexYes Thanks for your help and time. I feel silly that I didn't realize the >= was just for step 2 and I'd need to write a formula for each tally that I want to come up with.

Comment: select stage_name,  
    count(distinct application_id)
    from application_stages
    where case stage_name when 'Application Review' then 1 
    when 'Recruiter Screen' then 2 
    when 'Phone Interview' then 3
    when 'Interview' then 4
    when 'Interview 2' then 5
    when 'Offer' then 6
    when 'Hired' then 7
    end >=2
    group by stage_name;  This gives me a count of all possible stages.  However my initial question is to find only truly skipped stages.  For example:  a person can hit stage 1, 2, 4 and end at 5.  I want to account for 3 but not 6 or 7.

Comment: @WilsonS if you want to count only skipped stage #3 then you'll need `id<=4` which will count real 3s and missed 3s when there is a 4